# How to find latest timestamp for each day in JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have an entity which is something like

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ShopsTableID.class)
@Table(name = "SHOPS")
public class ShopsTable{
    
    @Id
    private String regionNumber;

    @Id
    private String shopNumber;

    @Id
    private String category;
    
    @Id
    private String workerId;

    @Id
    private String currency;

    @Id
    private Timestamp startOfValidity;

    @Id
    private Timestamp endOfValidity;
   
    private Integer flag;

    private Date recordDate;
...
```

and I need to extract every record between 2 timestamps (eg. from 2021-05-06... to 2021-01-01...) but records extracted needs to be the latest each day.

I tried to use criteriaBuilder.greatest on endOfValidity but it obviously only returns the very last record. How can I make the query return what I need? thank you in advance.

What I did for now:

```
public Optional<List<ShopsTable>> findByPeriod(String regionNumber,
                                                             String shopNumber,
                                                             String category,
                                                             String workerID,
                                                             String currency,
                                                             LocalDateTime startOfValidity,
                                                             LocalDateTime endOfValidity) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Table> cq = cb.createQuery(ShopsTable.class);

        Root<ShopsTable> tableRoot= cq.from(ShopsTable.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        predicates.add(cb.equal(tableRoot.get("regionNumber"), regionNumber));
        predicates.add(cb.equal(tableRoot.get("shopNumber"), shopNumber));
        predicates.add(cb.equal(tableRoot.get("category"), category));
        predicates.add(cb.equal(tableRoot.get("workerID"), workerID));
        predicates.add(cb.equal(tableRoot.get("currency"), currency));
        predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(tableRoot.get("startOfValidity"), startOfValidity));
        predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(tableRoot.get("endOfValidity"), endOfValidity));


        Subquery<String> maxSubQuery = cq.subquery(String.class);
        Root<ShopsTable> fromTable = maxSubQuery.from(ShopsTable.class);

        maxSubQuery.select(cb.greatest(fromTable.<String>get("endOfValidity")));

        Predicate p = cb.equal(tableRoot.get("endOfValidity"), maxSubQuery);

        cq.where(p);

        return Optional.of(em.createQuery(cq).getResultList());
    }
```

Comment: The criteria API is useful, but notoriously difficult. What I like to do is (1) write my query in plain SQL, make sure it works (2) write the criteria API code that seems to reproduce the plain SQL code (3) have JPA printing the SQL statements it executes to debug and tune.

Comment: You just need to group by`recordDate` in the subquery. Select the `id` from the subquery instead and correlate it with the main query